# Rails - Joining two separate tables to a third separate table to solve N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 separate tables `A`, `B` and `C`. Table `A` and table `B` are two separate tables that have very similar attrs, in fact table `B` is just an extension of table `A` but it had to be separated due to business requirements.  Both tables `has_many` relation to table `C`. Below is a better representation of the relationship between the three table

```ruby
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c, dependent: :destroy
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :c, dependent: :destroy
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a, optional: true
  belongs to :b, optional:true
end
```

So the problem comes when I'm trying querying information from table `C` and need the information from table `A` and `B` as well. If I do `C.where(user_id: 5).joins(:a)`, it only returns me the record that can join with `A`. Likewise for table `B`. But if I do `C.where(user_id: 5).joins(:a, :b)` I get a `[]` response. FWIW, the information I need from `A` and `B` are have the same column names when accessing them. Still very new to rails, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.joins` creates a LEFT INNER join which will only include rows with a match in the joined table. `.left_joins` creates a OUTER JOIN which will include rows even without a match. Neither will actually include any columns from the joined table in the result unless you actually manually select them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: Neither will actually solve a N+1 query issue - in that case you want `.includes` which will load the association in a single query. It does an outer join.

Comment: @max thanks for the suggestion. It looks like `.includes` might be good. I read your message earlier which mentioned polymorphic association which seems like it could be the better way to solve this in the long run. Would that be a better solution?

Comment: Yes and no. Polymorphic assocations will give you a single assocation. But you can't use foreign key constraints - its also a bit of hack that really just hides the problems related to the object–relational impedance mismatch. For example even when you join a polymorphic association you still have to use the correct table names in `.where`.